# Duplicating Product with 1500 variations breaks processing

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using a WordPress website and have woocommerce installed on the site. I am trying to duplicate a product having 1500 variations. While duplicating it breaks the processing after some time and I got below screen:

[image]

When I check open the product page and edit the duplicated product then I can see 1010 variations got copied but rest 490 variations are not copying successfully.

I increased `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` to `512M` and increased `max_execution_time` in `php.ini` to `600`.

Can anyone help me to get this issue fixed? I cannot add 1500 variations for each product manually.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Run it in CLI if possible. Other than that, probably increased the memory/execution time OR(and this is a better approach) do in batches of whatever you want(100, 500, etc).

Comment: It's a good thing you increase memory limits.  I am not sure if you are duplicating a product on the dashboard side of things, but I believe if you are duplicating a product (which is a type of post) it should also mean you need to increase the allowed input vars as you say there are 1500 variations, so just my guess, you can try increase max_input_vars in your php.ini.